# SwiftLint: Could not cast value of type 'Swift.Int64' to 'Swift.String', Build SwiftLint

Tags: ios, cocoapods, swift4, xcode9, swiftlint

I am integrating Swiftlint with my project in Xcode 9, Swift 4.

I installed swiftlint with Cocoapods. My Podfile looks like this:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'my_target' do
    # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
    use_frameworks!

    # Pods for my_target

    # https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire
    pod 'Alamofire'

    # https://fabric.io/kits/ios
    pod 'Fabric'

    # https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint
    pod 'SwiftLint'

end
```

When trying to build the project I see this error:

> Could not cast value of type 'Swift.Int64' (0x10ff35f80) to
>   'Swift.String' (0x10ff3c4d8).

The version installed in pods is 0.25.1
Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you are on the wrong version of SwiftLint.

As of this writing the latest version is `0.25.1`

You can see the latest version here:
https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint/releases

To see which version you are running: `swiftlint version`

**SwiftLint is NOT installed via CocoaPods!**

To upgrade to latest version:

- Delete SwiftLint: `brew uninstall swiftlint`
- Install SwiftLint: `brew install swiftlint`